# AVAsset in Swift2

Tags: swift2, xcode7, avasset

```
if let url = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL {
         audioAsset = (AVAsset.assetWithURL(url))
```

Some error in Xcode7 using AVAsset.
The error says:

'assetWithURL' is unavailable: use object construction 'AVAsset(URL:)'

after a while I found this solution:

```
                audioAsset = AVAsset(URL: url)
```

but I have no clue what this has to do with what the documentation says here for Swift2 written below. Why would´t you write the NSURL type here explicitly into the code? It looks a bit confusing.

convenience init(URL url: NSURL)

Comment: Can you describe or post the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>(I'd mark this as a dupe, because we've seen zillions of questions like this before, but I'm not finding well-generalized candidates at the moment...)</sub>

In general:

When you see a Swift interface that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
    init(thing: String)
}
```

You call it like this:

```
let myFoo = Foo(thing: "some text")
```

That's what the compiler calls "object construction" syntax.

(Replace `Foo`, `thing`, `String`, and `"some text"` with actual types and instances of those types as appropriate, of course.)

See [Objects and Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID464) in the opening "A Swift Tour" chapter of *The Swift Programming Language*. This chapter is really the first thing anyone should read for starting Swift.

---

By the way, this is true regardless of whether the initializer you see in the aforementioned Swift interface comes from Swift originally, or is imported from an Objective-C declaration like one of the following:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject

+ (Foo *)fooWithThing:(NSString *)thing;

- (instancetype)initWithThing:(NSString *)thing;

@end
```

Comment: Rickster, THX!!, its just about the writing style ion the documentation.

Comment: struggled with ´convenience init (URL url:NSURL)`, which looks a bit tautologic, doesn´t it?